# SOAP PHP Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: php, soap, null

I'm trying to call a function from this webservice:

http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx?WSDL

I'm sending all the requested params but I'm getting this error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
I think it's a server issue, but maybe I need to change something in my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx?WSDL',
                         array('location' => "http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx",
                               'trace'=>1, 
                               "cache_wsdl" => 0));

$params = array
(
    'providerId' => 109206,
    'fromDateStr' => "1985-12-19",
    'toDateStr' => "2013-05-06",
    'validTrades' => true,
    'lotSize' => "Mini",
    'start' => 0,
    'length' => 20,
    'sortBy' => "buy",
    'sortAscending' => true
);

try
{
    $result =  $client->GetProviderTrades($params);
}
catch (SoapFault $fault)
{
    print_r($fault);
}
```

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: You're not sending a required parameter 'source'?

Comment: @RMcLeod, There is no such parameter 'source' in the wsdl, so that cannot be it.

Comment: @Veda Has this ever been resolved? I'm facing the same issue here and can't seem to fix it. The parameter source doesn't exist in the WSDL file ether.

Comment: @WarreBuysse This is not my question, I tried looking into the problem, but for me the endpoint gives a server error (500).

Answer (score 0):

I tried with nusoap class and I get this error

> HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server http://www.zulutrade.com:81/WebServices/Performance.asmx, Error (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

So maybe it's a bug on their part

Comment: Did you set location to 80 port `http://www.zulutrade.com/WebServices/Performance.asmx` as it set by OP ?

Comment: There's no need to set the port

Comment: I don't - it's an inside code in the class of `nusoap` - I used this class with many web services and it worked fluency - I guess they know what they are doing

Answer (score 0):

You set all vars except one. `ArrayOfInt currencyIds;` is not set.

```
struct GetProviderTrades {
 int providerId;
 ArrayOfInt currencyIds;
 string fromDateStr;
 string toDateStr;
 boolean validTrades;
 LotSize lotSize;
 int start;
 int length;
 string sortBy;
 boolean sortAscending;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this: `code`$params = array
(
    'providerId' => 109206,
    'currencyIds' => array(1,2),
    'fromDateStr' => "1985-12-19",
    'toDateStr' => "2013-05-06",
    'validTrades' => true,
    'lotSize' => "Mini",
    'start' => 0,
    'length' => 20,
    'sortBy' => "buy",
    'sortAscending' => true
);`code`   And now the error is: "AnonymousType4f`2[System.Int32,Z.T[]] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor"

Comment: That is another question. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7377712/2123644

Comment: probably a bug on the other side